# material ui change textfield initial color

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, themes

I am trying to use mui TextField, I can change the color when focused (using theme). But however, I can't seem to find a way to changed its color (label, and border) when it's NOT focused (initial). Seems like it's always black, which means if I am using a black background it cannot be properly shown.

I would like a way to change its initial color to white, or any other color. Thanks.

Also, with the Select list, I have a same problem.
[image: Example]

Below is my code (unrelated things are removed):

```
class Register extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <Theme primary={{main: '#F5BD1F',dark: '#ffc100'}} secondary={{main : '#2a2a2a'}} >
            <Box sx={{backgroundColor: 'secondary.dark', display : 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', minHeight : '100vh'}}>
                <Box sx={{minHeight : '50vh', width : '50vw'}}>
                    <div style={{margin : '50px'}}>
                        <h1 style={{textAlign : 'center', fontSize: '20px'}}>Register a Metahkg account</h1>
                        <TextField sx={{marginBottom: '20px', input : {color : 'white'}}} variant="standard" type="text" label="Username" required fullWidth /> 
                        <TextField sx={{marginBottom: '20px', input : {color : 'white'}}} variant="standard" type="email" label="Email" required fullWidth/>
                        <TextField sx={{marginBottom: '20px', input : {color : 'white'}}} variant="standard" type="password" label="Password" required fullWidth/>
                        <Sex/><br/>
                        <Button variant="outlined">Register</Button>
                     </div>
                </Box>
            </Box>
            </Theme>)}}
```

Components:

Sex:

```
function Sex () {
    const [sex, setSex] = React.useState('');
    const changeHandler = 
    (e:any) => {setSex(e.target.value);}
    return (
        <FormControl sx={{ minWidth: 200 }}>
          <InputLabel>Sex</InputLabel>
          <Select value={sex} 
            label="Sex" onChange={changeHandler}>
            <MenuItem value={1}>Male</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={0}>Female</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>)}
```

Theme:

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'; 
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
    interface Theme {
      status: {
        danger: string;
      };}
    interface ThemeOptions {
      status?: {
        danger?: string;
      };}}
export default function Theme(props:any) {
  const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: props.primary,
      secondary: props.secondary
    }})
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            {props.children}
        </ThemeProvider>)}
```

[site](https://metahkg-dev.wcyat.engineer/register) 
[source code](https://gitea.wcyat.me/wcyat/metahkg/src/branch/master/src/pages/signup.tsx)

Comment: Why don't use snippet or online editor to help you better!?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You can use `stackoverflow` snippet or online editors like `codesandbox` to show us how your code works, then we can help you better.

Comment: Ok, I have added a link to codesandbox.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70435685/how-to-override-mui-5-input-label-background-color-for-custom-component/70436204

Comment: @SamA. thanks but this is for on focus. What I want is to change it for when NOT on focus.

Comment: It's done the same way I outline in my answer linking to the docs outlining how to target nested classes – just without the `:focus` pseudo-class. Your codesandbox above (as well as Netlify) isn't working. Please link to a working codesandbox and I'll provide the exact syntax for your use case.

Comment: @SamA. I have edited the links. Thanks.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-blackburn-joc02?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240909/discussion-between-wcyat-and-sam-a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See code below and [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-blackburn-joc02?file=/pages/index.js:0-1180) for a working example.

```js
import { CssBaseline, MenuItem, Stack, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { Fragment } from "react";

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)({
  "& label": {
    color: "white"
  },
  "&:hover label": {
    fontWeight: 700
  },
  "& label.Mui-focused": {
    color: "white"
  },
  "& .MuiInput-underline:after": {
    borderBottomColor: "white"
  },
  "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
    "& fieldset": {
      borderColor: "white"
    },
    "&:hover fieldset": {
      borderColor: "white",
      borderWidth: 2
    },
    "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
      borderColor: "white"
    }
  }
});

export default function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Stack
        spacing={2}
        margin={2}
        padding={2}
        height={"100vh"}
        component="form"
        backgroundColor="black"
      >
        <StyledTextField variant="outlined" label="Field" />
        <StyledTextField variant="outlined" label="Sex" select>
          <MenuItem value={1}>Male</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={0}>Female</MenuItem>
        </StyledTextField>
      </Stack>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem. Thank you.